# Rails scaffolding for test generating curious attributes for test fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When using rails scaffolding

```
rails g Somemodel nation:references
```

the fixtures automatically generated in the test directory take this form

```
one:
  nation: one
```

why is that?  the datatype is an integer and the attribute is `nation_id`.